# make error: "g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, makefile

I am new to Makefile and trying to create a cpp project with it.
Now I have only "hello world" program (only main.cpp file).
I can't stop getting this error when trying to compile with make:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -g -Wall -o sub_game  main.o
g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'sub_game' failed
make: *** [sub_game] Error 4
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, would appreciate your help.

This is the  Makefile:

```
# the compiler: gcc for C program, define as g++ for C++
CC = g++

# compiler flags:
#  -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
#  -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CXXLAGS  = -std=c++0x -g -Wall

# the build target executable:
TARGET = sub_game 

# define any libraries to link into executable:
LIBS = -lpthread -lgtest

# define the C source files
SRCS = ../src

# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'
# Below we are replacing the suffix .cc of all words in the macro SRCS
# with the .o suffix
#
#OBJ = $(SRCS)/main.cc
OBJ = main.o

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
#
INCLUDES = -I../include

all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
            $(CC) $(CXXLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ)

main.o : $(SRCS)/main.cpp

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It seems to be ok. Try to write a command of compilation bellow main.o rule.

Comment: I added the this rule and it's work:
    g++ -c $(SRCS)/main.cpp
Is that all I need to add?

Comment: I suppose it works now... By the way, use CXXFLAGS (not CXXLAGS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefile is used to compile programs without having to enter the command line each time AND to avoid re-compiling what doesn't need to.

Here with a little project of one file, you will re-compile your file each time, but with larger project, you will save a lot of time if you doesn't re-compile everything every time (for example if you work with some big library sources).

So you need to change a little your Makefile to avoid re-compiling what doesn't need to:

```
SRCS = ../src/main.cpp\ #Put here the relative path to your .cpp
       ../src/exemple_second_file.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o) # Here you get the .o of every .cpp

TARGET = sub_game # The executable name

CC = g++

CXXFLAGS = std=c++0x -g -Wall

LIBS = -lpthread -lgtest

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) # This line will compile to .o every .cpp which need to be (which have been modified)
           $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) # Linking (no need to CXXFLAGS here, it's used when compiling on previous line

ETC... # And so on...
```

Like that, your makefile will compile $(OBJS) automatically with $(CXXFLAGS) (main.o rule is implicit at least on linux, I don't know for winodws)

Cordially,
JM445

(Sorry for my English, I'm french)

Comment: Thank you that answer explained a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It needs a command bellow the main.o rule:

```
main.o : $(SRCS)/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I chose to use the answer above.